# Closed form for product of Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients, enumerative-combinatorics, stirling-numbers

What does the following expression evaluate to:

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dbinom{n}{k} \cdot k! \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix} \cdot k! \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

We know that $k! \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix} = n![x^n]:(e^x-1)^k$,  where $[x^k]:f(x)$ represents the coefficient of $x^k$ in the power series for $f(x)$. I was wondering if squaring $\left(\text{i.e., } k! \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix} \cdot k! \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix}\right)$ takes us to a different power series or just to a different coefficient in the same power series? I am looking for some clean closed form. A related expression:

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dbinom{n}{k} \cdot k! \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

is proven to be equal to $n^n$ in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3076350.

Comment: Mathematica answers GeneratingFunction::div: The generating function does not converge. through GeneratingFunction[Binomial[n, k]^2 *(k!)^2, k, x] .

Comment: @user64494 I've edited the question so that $k$ goes from $1$ to $n$. It should converge now, but I am looking for some clean final form for the expression.

Comment: The body and the title of the question were substantially changed (In the original question the generating function of $ \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix}^2\cdot k!^2$ was asked.) without any notice. This is not a good practice.

Comment: Apologies for that. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: for what it's worth, the series $1, 6, 147, 6940, 536405, 62352066,\ldots$ is not on oeis.org